# Java MAX and MIN value for integers

Tags: java, integer

Why is it that `(Integer.MAX_VALUE-Integer.MIN_VALUE) = -1`?

If you do it on a calculator it becomes a larger positive number but in java it's `-1`?

Comment: You're trying to subtract a negative number from MAX_VALUE. This wil thus try to add a positive number to MAX_VALUE. And by definition, no integer can be bigger than MAX_VALUE. So you have an integer overflow.

Comment: Look up Two's complement -- which is how Java represents negative non-floating point numbers, and int overflow, and then it will all make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integer overflow. If you go outside the bounds of what an Integer can hold it loops back around the other side.

For example try `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` and see what it gives you.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because of the arithmetic overflow: `MIN_VALUE` is a large negative, so subtracting it from `MAX_VALUE` produces a *positive* number which is beyond the capacity of an `int`.

If you would like to match the results that you get on a calculator, convert `int` values to `long` before subtraction:

```
long minInt = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
long maxInt = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
long diff = maxInt - minInt;
System.out.println(diff);
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/y4FATx)